# Coloring cells in Excel only of Last Column till Last Row and Last Row till Last Column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to highlight the entire row of the last cell till its last column and vice-versa for the entire column

I've used EntireRow and EntireColumn method and found that it is bit flawed for my approach as it colors whole row and column.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Range_End_Method()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim c As Range

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(lRow, lCol).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
Cells(lRow, lCol).EntireColumn.Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```vb
Range(Cells(lRow, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
Range(Cells(1, lCol), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
```

I would advise to declare and use a worksheet variable (at least), in case you want to call this sub from a different sheet and/or a different workbook.

Having said that, this is how your sub would look afterwards:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Range_End_Method()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet name")
    With ws
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
        Dim lCol As Long: lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1

        .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
        .Range(.Cells(1, lCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(174, 240, 194)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code runs perfectly, when I enter the sheetname in Line 3.
Instead can we Set ws variable to pull the active sheet name directly ? If yes, which function would we be using, because when I use Name method of ActiveSheet the code is running into error

Comment: Use `.ActiveSheet` instead of `.Sheets("sheet name")`